# How to Sort a Multi-dimensional Array by Value in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

Unfortunately, sorting tables in lua still remains difficult for me. Who can help me with the following question:

I would like to sort the table below by pluNumber:

Original tabel:

```
[3] = {
    [1] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '204',
            ['name'] = 'Cola Zero'
        }
    },
    [2] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '202',
            ['name'] = 'Sinas'
        }
    },
    [3] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '203',
            ['name'] = '7-up'
        }
    },
    [4] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '201',
            ['name'] = 'Cola'
        }
    }
}
```

New table:

```
[3] = {
    [1] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '201',
            ['name'] = 'Cola'
        }
    },
    [2] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '202',
            ['name'] = 'Sinas'
        }
    },
    [3] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '203',
            ['name'] = '7-up'
        }
    },
    [4] = {
        ['article'] = {
            ['pluNumber'] = '204',
            ['name'] = 'Cola Zero'
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I begin? I didn't succeed with a normal table.sort

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a function that tells Lua which of two table elements comes first.

```
table.sort(yourTable, function (a, b)
   return a.article.pluNumber < b.article.pluNumber end
```

Or

```
table.sort(yourTable, function (a, b)
   return a.article.pluNumber > b.article.pluNumber end
```

for decending order. This is explained in the Lua reference manual.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.sort